# Freeze on Login-Screen

Tags: greeter

all quick question about the login screen. I get a short freeze after boot (about 5 seconds). After boot login-screen background is gray, then it turns black and everything freeze, after that it turn again gray and is usable. After typing the password i get a complete black screen, mouse is moved to right bottom corner an i get a freeze again for a few seconds, after that my desktop appears and everything works fine.
Is that normal, i guess i have problems with drivers?

Thanks you! :)

Answer (score 0):

I also get sometime graphical issues, like the drop down-menue edges are not disappearing.

I tried to install mint driver manager, i have it now in my menu, but i cant start.

I run elementaryOS on a Notebook with an Ryzen 5 3500 and a integrated Readeon Vega.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's normal, a number of users are experiencing this issue since the start of November. It's nothing major, just a bug which the elementary team hopefully fixes quick.